# Selecting link in JS hidden dropdown menu

Tags: ruby, watir, watir-webdriver

I have a JavaScript hidden drop down menu that doesn't display the links unless the mouse hovers over it. I am trying to select a link within this menu using ruby watir-webdriver. I can select the link using .hover that shows the contents in the drop down menu. But I am having trouble selecting any of the links within the menu. In this case I want to click on the link "item1". 
Here is the html code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    <div id="menuWHeader" class="menuWf">
    <span class="menuTitle" onclick="goWindow(oprWin)"  onmouseout="menuCollapse('menuWContent')" onmouseover="menuExpand('menuWContent')"> window </span>
    <table id="menuWContent" class="menuContent" onmouseout="menuCollapse("menuWContent")" onmouseover="menuExpand("menuWContent")" style="visibility: hidden;">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
    <td class="menuItemNormal" onclick="goWindow(oprWin)" onmouseout="menuNormal(this)" onmouseover="menuSelect(this)">
    <img id="imgMenuWindow1" alt="" src="https://<myurl>/images/check-none.gif">
    item1
    </td> 
    </tr>
    <tr style="display:none">
    <td onclick="goWindow(crtWin)" onmouseout="menuNormal(this)" onmouseover="menuSelect(this)">
     <img id="imgMenuWindow2" alt="" src="https://<myurl>/images/check-none.gif">
    item2
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td class="menuItemNormal" onclick="goWindow(libWin)" onmouseout="menuNormal(this)" onmouseover="menuSelect(this)">
    <img id="imgMenuWindow3" alt="" src="https://vts42.commstor.crossroads.com/images/check-none.gif">
    item3
    </td>
    </tr>
```

The second table row item "item2" is hidden and does not display on the menu(greyed out in code). So only item1 & item3 are visible on the menu when I hover over it.

As mentioned I can hover on "window" which is the title of this menu and this then displays the menu items. I just cannot select any of the items in the list. Right now I am just trying to select item1. below is the watir code to hover on the menu.

```
 wb.div(:id => 'menuWHeader').span(:class =>'menuTitle').hover
```

I have tried a bunch of stuff that hasn't worked so I don't see any point in posting my failed attempts. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you want to click the `td` elements. This is based on the HTML having the `onclick` attribute for those elements.

It looks like the only unique property about the elements is there text. Depending how many tables you have on the page, you could do:

```
wb.td(text: 'item1').when_present.click
```

If there are other tables, you might want to scope the search to just the header `div`:

```
wb.div(:id => 'menuWHeader').td(text: 'item1').when_present.click
```

Note that the `when_present` method is included to ensure that Watir waits for the menu to appear before trying to click the `td`.